# python multiprocessing running same function with different args all stopped except for the last one

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm executing **a function** **multiple times** using **multiprocessing**. The function iterates part of a directory, depending on number of the CPU cores, and prints name of each file. **all processes stopped except for the last one.**

Code:

```
def worker(each_cpu_work_len, cpu_i):
    dirs = some_path.files(
    )[cpu_i - 1 * each_cpu_work_len:cpu_i * each_cpu_work_len]
    for a_file_in_dir in dirs:
        name = a_file_in_dir.basename()

        print(cpu_i, name)


def main():
    dirs_len = len(some_path.files())
    each_cpu_work_len = ceil(dirs_len / multiprocessing.cpu_count())

    procs = list()
    for cpu_i in range(1, multiprocessing.cpu_count() + 1):
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=worker,
            args=(each_cpu_work_len, cpu_i)
        )
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Results:

```
4 some_file1.txt
4 some_file2.txt
4 some_file3.txt
4 some_file4.txt
.
.
.
```

Also same results with multithreading. If you got an answer please also mention how can i implement something like multiprocessing.Manager().list() to pass to these functions. (So that they could append some variables to this server list)

Comment: You really should have implemented a `multiprocessing.Queue` and have the workers consume from that Queue. Then when all jobs have been queued, inject several "end your work and die" markers in the Queue that will signal to the workers that they should end.

Comment: Also, consider using `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of manually spinning up your workers for simple workloads.